# Only number appears in the phone field of the form

Tags: wordpress

I have a form on this site that I'm going to leave the link to, I managed to put a code to create a phone mask in the field, but I need the user to type only numbers and not letters.
if anyone can help i would appreciate it.

Link Form: https://www.viverbemcorretora.com.br/

The site was created in wordpress

this is the js code of the website:

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  const input = document.querySelector(".phone");
  const forminator_number_format = {
    run: function (event, form_id) {
      var _form = "#forminator-module-" + form_id,
        _form_el = $(_form);
      if (0 === _form_el.length) return;

      // Custom Phone Format = xxx-xxx-xxxx
      let _phones = _form_el.find(".phone .forminator-input");
      if (_phones.length) {
        _phones.each(function () {
          let _id = _form + " #" + $(this).attr("id");
          new Cleave(_id, {
            // prefix: '+',
            delimiters: ["(", ") ", "-"],
            blocks: [0, 2, 5, 4],
            uppercase: true,
          });
        });
      }
    },
  };

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("after.load.forminator", forminator_number_format.run);
    $(".forminator-custom-form").each(function () {
      forminator_number_format.run(null, $(this).data("form-id"));
    });
  });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the key pressed and check against an array of valid keys, like all numbers (numbers and keypad), backspace and delete. If not one of those then `preventDefault();`

```js
let phoneInput = document.querySelector('#input-phone');
let validKeys = [8,46,48,49,50,51,52,53,53,54,55,56,57,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105]

phoneInput.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  let pressedKey = e.keyCode
  if (!validKeys.includes(pressedKey)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<label for="phone">Phone:</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="input-phone" />
```